# named docker volume not updating using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to have one service to build my client side and then share it to the server using a named volume. Every time I do a `docker-compose up --build` I want the client side to build and update the named volume `clientapp:`. How do I do that?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2' 

volumes:
  clientapp:

services:
  database:
    image: mongo:3.4
    volumes:
      - /data/db
      - /var/lib/mongodb
      - /var/log/mongodb

  client:
    build: ./client
    volumes:
      - clientapp:/usr/src/app/client

  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - DB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR=database
    volumes:
      - clientapp:/usr/src/app/client
    depends_on:
      - client
      - database
```

client Dockerfile

```
FROM node:6

ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

# builds my application into /client
CMD ["npm", "build"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251094/i-want-to-share-code-content-across-several-containers-using-docker-compose-volu/44265470 (sorry about the instant close there a second ago)

Answer (score 14):

By definition, a volume is the persistent directories that docker won't touch other than to perform an initial creation when they are empty. If this is your code, it probably shouldn't be a volume.

With that said, you can:

1. Delete the volume between runs with `docker-compose down -v` and it will be recreated and initialized on the next `docker-compose up -d`.
2. Change your container startup scripts to copy the files from some other directory in the image to the volume location on startup.
3. Get rid of the volume and include the code directly in the image.

I'd recommend the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would I go about implementing #3? What do you mean by including the code directly in the image?

Comment: For #3, you delete the volume lines from your docker-compose.yml and keep the `COPY` lines in your Dockerfile.

Comment: If I do that, how would my server project use the client files? Where would they be located?

Comment: If your server container needs the code to run, include the code in the server image.

Comment: I don't know how to include the code from client to the server image without using volumes...my client builds the app into /usr/src/app/client on that service. Somehow I need my server to pull in that directory or have the client share it with server. Could you provide a small example to illustrate your point?

Comment: For option #3, you can't build the code inside of the other running container. It relies on your code being built either inside of each image, or outside of the images and `COPY` that in during the build. If you need this to change at runtime, you'd need option #2, but that won't be portable to swarm mode without some kind of external data storage.

Comment: I'd rather keep everything inside the images. So far I haven't been able to get it to work, even with the linked questions. I'm probably just going to end up putting the 2 project together because I can't figure this out

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you shared your src folder like this :

```
...
volumes:
      - ./my_src:/path/to/docker/src
...
```

What worked for me is to chown the `my_src` folder :

```
chown $USER:$USER -R my_src
```

It turned out some files were created by root and couldn't be modified by docker.

Hope it helps !